# Family Tech Support: Remote Support/Training/Control/?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-control, apple-remote-desktop

I'm a non-Mac user who just agreed to take on support for my Mac-using 75 year old mother.
 
Looking for any suggestions for *free* remote troubleshooting/remote control?

- Rustdesk viable/good?  Other FOSS viable?
- GotoMeeting/GoToAssist? Other non-FOSS with really free home use?
- Something in-house that I'm missing? Note: not just looking for screen-sharing. Want to be able to control her keyboard and mouse, demo program usage, resolve issues, etc.

Comment: Try the team viewer, it worked for me from US to Europe